# Smooth quantile estimation algorithm

Tags: r, nonparametric, quantiles, kernel-smoothing, quantile-regression

I came across the paper of M. C. Jones on smooth quantile estimation ([link](http://www.ism.ac.jp/editsec/aism/pdf/044_4_0721.pdf)). He proposes using the following estimator for quantile function $Q$ around point $p$:
$$
\hat{Q}(p) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{(i)}\int_{(i-1)/n}^{i/n} h^{-1} K\left(\frac{p-y}{h}\right)dy,
$$
where $X_{(i)}$ is the ordered sample, $h$ is the smoothing parameter and $K$ is the kernel function. I tried to code the function in R but the estimates are quite far from the empirical quantiles.

For a univariate sample $X$, bandwidth $h$ and quantile $p$ the code goes

```
SmoothQuantile = function(x, h, p) {
xs = sort(x)
n  = length(x)
q  = 0
for(i in 1:n) {
   q = q + xs[i] * integrate(function(y) { 1/h * dnorm((p-y)/h) }, lower = (i-1)/n, upper = i/n)$value
}
return(q)
}
```

It seems a quite straightforward implementation of the estimator above. Any ideas what can be potentially driving the results so far away from the empirical quantiles?

To compare the results use

```
x=rnorm(100, 0, 1)
p=0.01
h=0.3043                #normal scale bandwidth value
quantile(x, p)          #empirical quantile
SmoothQuantile(x, h, p) #smooth quantile
```

Comment: Can you also add code showcasing how the estimator fails?

Comment: I provided the example code how to compare the results, with the bandwidth value calculated from the normal-scale method.

Comment: CV is not intended as a resource for software specific questions. You are better off posting your query to Stack Exchange or one of the R community support sites.